# Que signifie « Mapi » ou « Ma pie »

Tags: sens

Récemment j'ai entendu un jeune s'adressant à un autre : "Hé ma pi" ou "hé Mapi", je pense que c'est un langage de jeunes

Pour le contexte c'était dans une discussion bien entamé dans la rue, et l'intonation me faisait penser À une phrase à part entière.

Pourriez-vous m'aider sur la signification de ce terme ?

Comment: Pourrais-tu préciser le contexte ? Cela pourrait être utile pour comprendre de quelle expression il s'agit exactement.

Comment: Sans contexte et sans certitude de la prononciation, il est impossible de répondre, même avec beaucoup d'imagination. Pour le peu qu'on sait c'est peut-être simplement le surnom d'un des protagonistes...

Comment: Surnom de l'un des 2, mot d'argot local... aucun moyen d'en savoir plus sans davantage de détails sur le contexte.

Answer (score 1):

Bonjour, je crois que "Mappy", dérivé de "map" ("carte" dans la langue de Shakespeare) désigne un logiciel de géo-positionnement par satellite utilisé sur les appareils cellulaires de dernière génération. Cela pourrait-il correspondre au contexte dans lequel tu l'as entendu ?

Comment: C'était dans la rue, un jeune qui parle à un autre. Je ne sais pas si ça peut aider mais au vu des téléphones portables que détenaient les deux jeunes on ne peut dire que ça soit de dernière génération...

Comment: Mappy c'est un simple site/app d'itinéraire, mais je doute que des jeunes d'aujourd'hui l'utilisent ou y face référence.

Answer (score 1):

Bonjour, vu le contexte donné ça pourrait être un dérivé du très commun "Ma caille" pour interpeler quelqu'un, en changeant l'oiseau par une pie.

Answer (score 0):

Bonsoir, j'ai déjà entendu un jeune prononcer «Mapi» sans en comprendre le sens. J'habite à Toulouse, cette expression pourrait-elle être propre à la ville ou la région? Il serait intéressant de se demander si ce terme peut prendre racine dans des expressions vernaculaires plus anciennes.
Malheureusement je ne m'y connais pas assez dans ce domaine, mais peut-être est-ce une piste à explorer?

En espérant avoir pu vous aider même maigrement.